# How to calculate SNR of a signal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

I want to calculate SNR of the noisy signal and the filtered signal. I used this following code but I am not sure whether the result is correct or not. Can somebody help me?

```
%generate the noisy signal which will be filtered
x= cos(2*pi*12*[0:0.001:1.23]);
x(end) = [];
[b,a] = butter(2,[0.6 0.7],'bandpass');
filtered_noise = filter(b,a,randn(1, length(x)*2));
y = (x + 0.5*filtered_noise(500:500+length(x)-1))/length(x)*2;

%Use matlabs built-in buttord function to get the optimum order to meet a      
specification
[N,Wn] = buttord(0.1, 0.5, 5, 40)

%use the N and Wn values obtained above to design the filter in the usual 
way
[b,a] = butter(N, Wn, 'low');

%filter the signal and plot the ouput of the filter
Y_filtered = filter(b,a,y);

%calculation of snr before filtering
snr_before = mean(x.^2) / mean(filtered_noise.^2);
snr_before_db = 10 * log10(snr_before) % in dB

%calculation of snr after filtering
residual_noise = x - Y_filtered; 
snr_after = mean(x.^2) / mean(residual_noise.^2); 
snr_after_db = 10 * log10(snr_after)
```

Results that I got is:

```
snr_before_db =
      6.8725
snr_after_db =
      0.0132
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its right way to calculate PSNR before and after filtering. Also, the way you are calculating the PSNR is not correct. It is possible to calculate PSNR only after filtering. Try this

```
peaksnr = psnr(X,Y_filtered)
```

or

```
MSE = (1/length(X))*sum((X-Y_filtered).^2);
peaksnr = 10*log10(max(X(:))^2/MSE);
```

Comment: Okay. Then, how can I know the value of the SNR before the filtering? So that I can compare the result between different types of filter.